# filter_var and SplInt Quirkieness

Tags: php, filter-var, splint

I'm assuming that this is just due to the relatively new state of the SPL_Types extension.  You would think this would have a predictable response.

```
$integer = new \SplInt( 5 );

if( false === filter_var( $integer, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array( 'options' => array( 'min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 9 ) ) ) )
{
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException( sprintf( 'An integer value of 1 through 9 is required, %s "%s" given.', gettype( $integer ), $integer ) );
}
```

Result:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'An integer value of 1 through 9 is required, object "5" given.'
```

Comment: I guess and int and an SplInt are not the same type..

Comment: You could try to cast $integer to a string in the filter_var call

Comment: Well, yes, typing as an `(int)` would solve the problem here.  I was more annoyed with the fact that `filter_var` and `SplInt` do not play nicely together as the latter is, technically, an Object.